# Infinite descendant sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

"Show that the order $(A,<)$ is well ordering if and only if there no exists infinite descendant sequences in $A$".

Can you help me whit this problem, please, what happens is that my professor isn't gave us the definition of "infinite descendant sequences", so i haven't enough basis to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: can you specify your definition of well.ordering.

Comment: A set $A$ is well ordering if all no-empty subset of $A$ have a minimum element.

Comment: A very standard equivalent one (which is i guess the thing you have to prove) is the following : 

Every decreasing sequence of elements of $A$ must be finite.

Comment: Ok, i think i have the idea, i'll try to prove in this way, thanks.

Comment: I can put this as an answer to close the question if you want.